# save data to firestore from react on submit

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, redux-toolkit

I'm moving from Angular to react but I'm struggle to save some data to a collection in firestore.

The path I want to save to is : users/uid/pred

In Angular I do this and it works:

```
savePredictions(data: any, uid: string) {
    let v: any = Object.values(data);
    v.forEach((x: any[]) => {
      x.forEach((match) => {
        this.db
          .collection("users")
          .doc(uid)
          .collection("pred")
          .doc(match.matchday)
          .set({ [match.matchId]: match }, { merge: true });
      });
    });
  }
}
```

In React I do this and it fails:

```
const onSubmit = () => {
    const userId = user?.uid;
    const docRef = doc(db, "users", userId as string, "pred");
    setDoc(docRef, predictions.fixtures);
    console.log("SUBMIT TO FIREBASE:", predictions.fixtures);
};
```

Authentication is working and I can receive data from the database, also I have data in my predictions.fixtures to send, it is an array.

Can anyone show me code had to save to this collection called 'pred'?

Comment: Please report the error either in the console or the error returned from firestore

Answer (score 1):

I had to use the setDoc with doc, which creates a new doc with collection. I had to run it in a forEach loop because my data is an array so each iteration has to be setDoc BUT because the name of the doc changes:

```
"gameweek" + String(index + 1)
```

it creates a new doc, thus making my saved data in different docs and nicer to view in firestore database.

```
const onSubmit = () => {
        setShowSave(false);
        const userId = user?.uid;
        predictions.fixtures[0].forEach((el: any, index: number) => {
            setDoc(doc(db, "users", userId as string, "predx", "gameweek" + String(index + 1)), {
                ["gameweek" + String(index + 1)]: el,
            });
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

there is three possible reasons.

->version difference - you are using version 8 in angular while version 9 in react.and all most many syntax changes in firebase 8 to 9

-> your collection name should be in string format (prediction.fixtures).

-> you have to give value of your fields in your setDoc. the syntax of setDoc is setDoc(db , "collection-name" , field-value).